# Windows forms web browser control zoom level

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm using a web browser control to display some on-the-fly generated HTML documents in my application.

Problem is, on my machine said documents are displayed kinda zoomed in. On other colleagues' computers, everything looks "normal". It has to be some kind of local setting but I can't find where to change it.

I can CTRL + Scroll wheel to zoom out, but zoom level is not retained. As far as I can see, there's no easy way to set the predefined zoom level programmatically.

It may be a long shot but I fear it has something to do with Internet Explorer (which I never use) and its settings. Changing control type is not a viable option, unfortunately.

Any help would really be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So basically you're saying it's not keeping the zoom you're specifying even manually? Have you tried handling the `DocumentCompleted` Event and applying `webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:200%";` ? Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a difference to be found in the properties inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom` on your machine compared to the ones that look "normal"?

Comment: Internet Explorer respects to the windows scale settings. As a result the size that you will see on `WebBrowser` control on a system having scaling 100, is different from the size which you see on `WebBrowser` control on a system having scaling 150, while both `WebBrowser` controls set to 100% zoom.  
The reason is because of scaling. The scaling factor is same is Windows scaling factor divided by 100 or `physicalScreenHeight/logicalScreenHeight`.

Comment: I'm slowly testing everything posted here, meanwhile thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 11):

> Problem is, on my machine said documents are displayed kinda zoomed
>   in.

Internet Explorer respects to the windows scale settings. As a result the size that you will see on `WebBrowser` control on a system having scaling 100, is different from the size which you see on `WebBrowser` control on a system having scaling 150, while both `WebBrowser` controls set to 100% zoom.

The reason is because of scaling. The scaling factor is same as Windows scaling factor divided by 100 or `physicalScreenHeight/logicalScreenHeight`.

> As far as I can see, there's no easy way to set the predefined zoom
>   level programmatically.

In fact there is. To change the zoom level of Web Browser control, you can get [`IWebBrowser2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752127(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) instance from the [`WebBrowser.ActiveXInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.activexinstance?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property and then using its [`ExecWB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa752117(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method, set set the zoom this way:

```
int OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM = 63;
int OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2;
dynamic iwb2 = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
object zoom = 200; //The value should be between 10 , 1000
iwb2.ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, zoom, zoom);
```

You can also add reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw.dll)` and cast `WebBrowser.ActiveXInstance` to `SHDocVw.WebBrowser` and use `ExecWB` method.  But above code does the trick without adding any reference.

Web browser zoom is completely different from CSS3 zoom. But you may want to know about how to set document body zoom: `webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:200%";`

All above codes should be run after document has been completed.

Comment: Zooming via ExexWB indeed works. I wonder if it has something to do with my secondary screen. Our primary screens are identical but if Windows bases his assumptions on screen #1 than this may be the problem. In Windows settings, screen #2 is marked as primary screen.

Comment: Internet Explorer respects to the windows scale settings. Each screen can have it's own scale setting. Check the scale factor of that screen in Windows.

Comment: Problem not entirely solved but at least I was able to zoom the control at will by using ExecWB. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with Screen Resolution. Your screen is on less resolution setting whereas your colleagues' screen is set with higher resolution than yours.

Change your screen resolution to same as your colleagues' screen resolution or vice-versa and you should see the issue resolved.

> **Note:** The decision of which resolution is correct depends completely on your client needs and expectations. You might also want to set right expectation from the start to ensure not to disappoint the client later in the stage.

Comment: Same resolution, same computer and screen models actually

Answer (score 3):

Might it be that your display is scaled?
(Assuming Win 10, but older versions must be pretty similar)

desktop, context menu -> display settings -> under Scale and Layout, is yours set to a value higher than 100%?

Comment: It's 100, same goes for my colleagues

Answer (score 2):

Its windows 10 issue all HDPI devices goes to 200% zoom level automatically.
To get started, right-click any empty space on your desktop and select Display settings towards the bottom of the context menu. Alternatively, you can go to Start > Settings > System > Display. The Settings app in Windows 10 is ready for per-monitor display scaling.

There is no proper fix for it as I have three screens and all has different display hdpi and I get 200% zoom automatically . So 1 screen shows it ok and other 2 are extra zoomed.

```
window.onload = function() {
var currFFZoom = 1;
var currIEZoom = 100;

$('#In').on('click',function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom += step; 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom += step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});

$('#Out').on('click',function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom -= step;                 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});};


<input type="button" id="Out" alt="Zoom Out"/>
<input type="button" id="In" alt="Zoom In"/>
```