# How can I enable zooming on a 1 page, but not all the rest in .NET winforms webbrowser?

Tags: .net, winforms, browser, zooming, touchscreen

I have a kiosk running on windows 10 using a touch-screen. my app is a .NET winforms app. Basically just a webbrowser control taking up the whole form. And as such, the whole app is zoomable by default it seems. I only want 1 page that has maps to be zoomable (using pinch zoomer API). So is there a way with this hardware/software setup to disable zoom everywhere except on that 1 page where I want it?

I've tried going through all the hardware config to see if there was a setting there I could use, but nothing.

As mentioned, the only page I want to zoom on uses Pinch Zoomer JQuery Plugin. So I think even if there is a way to disable overall zoom for IE, it would probable then not allow the zooming where I need it?

Any help on this is appreciated. I did fing a blog about hacking the registry to disable IE zoom in 'kiosk' mode but again, I need it for my maps page.

Comment: Browser zoom is different from css zoom. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52255558/3110834).

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122485/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-zoom-content) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control). You should be able to set the zoom level at one page and disable on others

Comment: But I want users to be able to pinch zoom in/out on the map to certain areas, which is inside a div, so not the whole page. It works great inside a normal browser, but not inside the .NET shell app for some reason. Actually a separate issue I guess but when I try to pinch zoom within the app on the map, I get the 'not allowed' mouse icon.

Comment: If it doesn't work on the div and instead it's zooming the whole browser, then it probably means you need to load the browser in IE 11 mode. Thake a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38514184/3110834).

Comment: I found this works in Chrome:

     `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     },{passive: false});`

but not IE....which I would prefer, otherwise I have to see if I can use Chromium control. I have tried CEFSharp but when I run on Windows 10 nothing happens. No error or anything.

Comment: ok got CEFSharp to work, just had to install VC++ files.